# Extracting two elements using grepl()

Tags: r, grepl

I have a dataset called "data" that looks like this:

[image: data]

I am trying to create a new variable, called "Group" which codes elements in the "FileName" variable as the following:

- anything with element HC will be labelled as "HC PBMC"
- anything with elements SF and PBMC will be labelled as "AS PBMC"
- anything with elements SF and SFMC will be labelled as "AS SFMC"

In order to do this, I wrote this code:

```
data$Group<- ifelse(grepl("HC",data$FileName),"HC",
                    ifelse(grepl("SF & PBMC",data$FileName),"AS PBMC",
                           "AS SFMC"))
```

However, anything with elements SF and PBMC did not code as "AS PBMC" correctly. Instead it just skipped that condition and labelled it as "AS SFMC". Please see below:

[image: data]

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: [Please do not post images of code and/or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution based on what you tried would be:

```
data$Group <- ifelse(grepl("HC", data$FileName),
                     "HC",
                     ifelse(
                             grepl("SF", data$FileName) & grepl("PBMC", data$FileName),
                             "AS PBMC",
                             "AS SFMC"
                     ))
```

Comment: This will however code anything that doesn't match `"HC"` or `"SF"`+`"PBMC"` as `"AS SFMC"`  - I think you need *another* nested `ifelse` for `"SF"`+`"SFMC"` to account for any values that might lie out-of-range (i.e. error values etc).

Comment: That is true, I merely fixed OPs solution, @thelatemail. `dplyr::case_when()` is a great alternative for these kind of nested `ifelse` statements by allowing to provide a default value.

Answer (score 0):

First note that "&" does not have the meaning of a logical "and" inside a regex. You could certainly achieve what you want with some sophisticated regex, but wouldn't it be more transparent to extract the components you consider for naming the groups first and then assign the cases in a second step?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  FileName = c("HC1788 PBMC", "SF71 PBMC", "SF70_2 SFMC")
)

df |> 
  # extract components
  mutate(
    A = str_extract(FileName, "^HC|^SF"),
    B = str_extract(FileName, "PBMC$|SFMC$")
  ) |> 
  # assign groups
  mutate(Group = case_when(
    A == "HC" ~ "HC PBMC",
    A == "SF" & B == "PBMC" ~ "AS PBMC",
    A == "SF" & B == "SFMC" ~ "AS SFMC"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   FileName    A     B     Group  
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 HC1788 PBMC HC    PBMC  HC PBMC
#> 2 SF71 PBMC   SF    PBMC  AS PBMC
#> 3 SF70_2 SFMC SF    SFMC  AS SFMC
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this is a little bit too much effort for this simple task.